# Does closure always needs be in IIFE?

Tags: javascript, closures

Any function within function forms a closure. **Do closures always needs to be in an immediately invoked function?**

The first example is where a closure is formed within an iife and works as expected, gives "8" and "7" as output.

```js
var cat = (function (){
  var lives = 9;
  return function() {
    return --lives;
  }
}());
console.log("iife");
console.log(cat());
console.log(cat());
```

In the below example the closure does not work as expected, prints the same value every time.

```js
var cat = function (){
  var lives = 9;
  return function() {
    return --lives;
  }
};

console.log("no iife");
console.log(cat()());
console.log(cat()());
```

Comment: Second example, you are creating a new closure *every* time you call `cat()`. So you are getting the correct result but your expectation is that there would be a single closure instead of one for each call.

Comment: No it just helps keeping from polluting the higher scope.  The reason why you get the same result is because you call `cat()` again which creates a new function with the initial value. Assign `cat()` to a variable and call it, `temp=cat(); temp(); temp();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A closure is just the link between a function and the scope in which it was created, link which exists when the function uses a variable from this scope.

You have this problem because you don't keep the closure: you're recreating it at every `console.log` when you call `cat()`.

Change

```
console.log(cat()());
console.log(cat()());
```

into

```
let c = cat();
console.log(c());
console.log(c());
```